# Magento wsdl file (api/V2_soap?wsdl=1)

Tags: magento, wsdl

I have a server and I would like to hide the contents of the wsdl file from the outside world, from regular, everyday users/attackers who enumerate my network and find this file. How can I do this? If the answer is .htaccess, where should I put this .htaccess file? There is no /api/ folder in my server.

Thanks